# Get individual values from an array created from a resultset in java

Tags: java, arrays, resultset

I have an array that was created from an ArrayList which was in turn created from a ResultSet. This array contains rows of database table and each row (with several columns based on my query) exists as a single element in the array. So far so good. My problem is how to get individual values (columns) from each row which, I said earlier, now exists as an element. I can get each element (row, of course) but that is not what I want. Each element is a composite of several values and how to get those? I am a beginner and really stuck here. I think this all make sense. Here's the code how I created the array.

```
List resultsetRowValues = new ArrayList();      
while (resultSet.next()){
    for (int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++) {
        resultsetRowValues.add(resultSet.getString(i));
    }
}

String[] databaseRows = (String[]) resultsetRowValues.toArray(new String[resultsetRowValues.size()]);
```

EDIT: More explanation
My MySQL query is as follows:

```
String query = "SELECT FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, ADDRESS FROM SOMETABLE WHERE CITY='SOMECITY'";
```

This returns several rows in a ResultSet. And according to the sample query each element of an array will cotain three values (columns) i.e FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME and ADDRESS. But these three values exist in the array as a single element. While I want each column separately from each element (which is actually a row of the database table). When I iterate through the aarray using for loop and print the values to the console, I get output similar to the following:

```
Doe
Jhon
Some Street (End of First element)
Smith
Jhon
Some Apartment (End of Second element and so on)
```

As it is evident from the output, each element of the contains three values which are printed on separate lines.
How to get these individual values.

Comment: need some more clarity, an eg would be greatly appreciated

Comment: The intermediate `List` makes no sense, you end up with line1-row1 ... line1-rowX followed by line2-row1 ... line2-rowX and that's a problem.

Comment: @Saurabh Jhunjhunwala I have provided more detail.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like that:

```
List<Map<String, String>> data = new ArrayList<>();      
while (resultSet.next()){
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++) {
        map.put("column" + i, resultSet.getString(i));
    }
    data.add(map)
}

// usage: data.get(2).get("column12") returns line 3 / column 12
```

Note that there are other possible options (2D-array, [guava Table](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Table.html), ...)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but what is `"row"`?

Comment: Edited to fix that, sorry